# A word like "bid" in increasing manner but used metaphorically

Tags: single-word-requests, metaphors

So there’s a word (verb) we use in colloquial Egyptian Arabic, mostly in discussions or arguments. When i saying it I’m stating that the other person only interested in showing that he does/ has more of what I’m saying. He could show he is in more pain if i complained, he might show more ethical/ polite attitude if I’m being polite and so on.
One more example:

- everyone is trying to get on the game of who suffers more, then everyone is (that verb).
- Alice: i bought a PlayStation 4. Bob: i bought a PlayStation 5. Alice: why the fuck should you always (that verb)

In standard Arabic it doesn’t give the metaphorical meaning but rather the litteral actual meaning and it translates to bid in increasing manner in an auction.

Comment: https://dilbert.com/search_results?terms=Topper

Answer (score 1):

Your two examples are slightly different, and different phrases are used:

> Everyone is trying to get on the game of who suffers more, then everyone is (that verb).

**upping the ante**.

OED:

> **Ante**: (n.) 1. In poker and similar card games. a. A mandatory stake put into the pot or betting pool before play begins
>
> **to up the ante:** (v.) figurative. :  *[...] (b) (in extended use) to increase what is at stake or under discussion.*
>
> 1986   Telegraph (Sydney) (Nexis) 5 Nov.   *Mr Cain said he did not wish to make ‘gratuitous threats’ or ‘up the ante’ during the dispute [with nurses].*

> Alice: i bought a PlayStation 4. Bob: i bought a PlayStation 5. Alice: why the fuck do you always (that verb)

**go one better /top everyone's story.**

> P5 (a) to go one better: to (narrowly) outdo someone or surpass a previous effort or achievement.
>
> 2007   B. Warner Sit down & shut up xxi. 209   *When just having short hair didn't seem radical enough, the hardcore punks went one better and shaved it all off.*

> **to top IV. 12.b. To surpass, excel, outdo; to cap.**
>
> a1616   W. Shakespeare Coriolanus (1623) ii. i. 20   *Topping all others in boasting.*

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you [**Up the Ante**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/up_the_ante), you are raising the stakes of the game being played.

> Holier than thou. Mine is shinier than yours, and of course bigger.

Oxford Lexico has it this way:

> Increase what is at stake or under discussion, especially in a conflict or dispute.
> Say, "He decided to up the ante in the trade war."

Also called **one upmanship**.

You would think the Bible asks us not to take personal revenge (*nekama*), as in "Remember you wouldn't lend me your ax? Well, no ax for you today." But it also asks us not to hold a grudge [(*netira*)](https://www.etzion.org.il/en/shiur-28netira), as in the more subtle "Remember you wouldn't lend me your ax? Well, *today, I lend you mine!*" Now there you **up the ante**.